# Active Admin Model Index Page (Model List View) define order of displayed fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is there an easy way to change the order of displayed field of a Model in the Active Admin index view for a model? I have far more fields then Active Admin can display but i want to be able to define the most relevant fields for the user in this view.

The relevant fields in my case (see screenshot) are hidden (..) by Active Admin and only can be seen then i change to the show view of a model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define the fields to display in the index view inside the ActiveAdmin model configuration, i.e.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Place do
  config.sort_order = 'name_asc'

  index do
    column :name
    column :address
    column :place_type
    column :published
    default_actions
  end
end
```

You can read more about ActiveAdmin options here: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html

Comment: thx for your comment which let me recognize that i'm using rails admin and not active admin ... doo sorry about my confusion ;) should take things easier i guess

Comment: @jethroo LOL, glad I could be helpful :)